# how to substract and add id's with decimal and alphanumeric

Tags: php

Im stuck on this for quite some time. I have to work with identifiers that are always 4 characters long and consist of 0-9a-z. An example would be `iulz`. So the range would be something like:

`0000 0001 0002 ... 0009 000a 000b ... 000z 0010 ... zzzz`

So in the case of my example, `iulz` I know that the ID before that would be `iuly` and after that `ium0`. But i cannot seem to work out how to calculate this. The functions `hexdec` and `dechex` would help me if they would include the whole alphabet.

My first try was to make a logical list with some for loops but this takes an impossible amount of memory. I am looking for a way to make the following two functions:

```
function getNext(string $id) : string { ... }
function getPrev(string $id) : string { ... }
$this->getNext('iulz') // returns 'ium0'
$this->getPrev('iulz') // returns 'iuly'
```

Can anyone get me on the right track here? Thnxz!

Comment: Can you tell me how did you arrive at `000a` from `0009`?

Comment: @nice_dev I believe he created his own count base, where `a` is the next figure after `9`, and so on with the rest of the english alphabet

Comment: @nice_dev we are counting from 0 to 9 and then a to z.

Comment: @DJQ Wasn't really helpful though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your encoding scheme contains 36 symbols (digits from `0` to `9` and letters from `a` to `z`), so a possible approach is to implement a math with Base36. PHP supports `base_convert()` function to convert a number between arbitrary bases.

```
<?php

function getNext($id) {
    $n = base_convert($id, 36, 10);
    $n = $n + 1;
    $n = base_convert($n, 10, 36);
    $n = str_pad($n, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $n;
}

function getPrev($id) {
    $n = base_convert($id, 36, 10);
    $n = $n - 1;
    $n = base_convert($n, 10, 36);
    $n = str_pad($n, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $n;
}

$id = 'iulz';
echo "ID: " . $id . ", next ID: " . getNext($id) . ", previous ID: " . getPrev($id) . ".";

?>
```

Result:

```
ID: iulz, next ID: ium0, previous ID: iuly.
```

As an additional note, you need to define the expected behaviour of the functions, if the `$id` is outside the `[0000 .. zzzz]` range.

Comment: Don't forget to pad the result (e.g. with `str_pad($value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)`).

Comment: @Olivier, thanks, very important note.

Comment: With 'zzzz' this will return '10000', which might not be what the OP wants. Maybe he wants an exception thrown, or restart with '0000'. Nonetheless an elegant solution.

Comment: @lukas.j, thanks, I added a note in the answer.

Comment: @Zhorov: that worked! I did not think of using `base_convert`. You are a life saver!

Comment: @Zhorov The note you added does not address what I meant. I meant that _getNext('zzzz')_ will return '10000', which is outside of the valid range as per the OP. And _getPrev('0000')_ will also return a value outside of the valid range. In that case you have an error because on the third line $n will be -1 in _base_convert($n, 10, 36);_, and `base_convert` casts _-1_ to a string, so you'll have a 'Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion' notice. So both function need an edge case test before the return on the last line, and then return false or throw an exception or so.

Comment: @lukas.j, my idea was to check the result from the `base_convert($id, 36, 10)` call (the return values from `base_convert('0000', 36, 10)` and `base_convert('zzzz', 36, 10)` are `0` and `1679615`).

Comment: @Zhorov That is of course maybe even better. But of course the OP should state what the functions should return in these two edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
function previousId(string $alphabet, string $id)
{
  $length = strlen($id);
  $first = $alphabet[0];
  $last = $alphabet[strlen($alphabet) - 1];
  if ($id === str_repeat($first, $length)) {
    return '––––';
  }
  for ($len = $length - 1; $len >= 0; $len--) {
    if (str_ends_with($id, str_repeat($first, $len))) {
      $pos = $length - $len - 1;
      $char = $alphabet[strpos($alphabet, $id[$pos]) - 1];
      return substr($id, 0, $pos) . $char . str_repeat($last, $len);
    }
  }
}

function nextId(string $alphabet, string $id)
{
  $length = strlen($id);
  $first = $alphabet[0];
  $last = $alphabet[strlen($alphabet) - 1];
  if ($id === str_repeat($last, $length)) {
    return '––––';
  }
  for ($len = $length - 1; $len >= 0; $len--) {
    if (str_ends_with($id, str_repeat($last, $len))) {
      $pos = $length - $len - 1;
      $char = $alphabet[strpos($alphabet, $id[$pos]) + 1];
      return substr($id, 0, $pos) . $char . str_repeat($first, $len);
    }
  }
}
```

These two functions take an arbitrary alphabet (of unique characters). The id can be of any length smaller than the length of the alphabet string. Both error condition could and should be added to these function.

If there is no preceding value for *previousId* the function currently returns the message '----' for illustration purposes. Possible real values: *false*, *null*, wrap around to the last value ('zzzz'), or maybe throw a `RuntimeException` or test the input value before calling *previousId*. Same applies for a call of *nextId* with an id of 'zzzz', which could return '0000', or false, or null, etc.

```
$alphabet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$id = 'iulz';

echo previousId($alphabet, $id) . " < $id > " . nextId($alphabet, $id) . "\n";

// Outputs: iuly < iulz > ium0
```